# Installing Metasoploit Framework on Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, metasploit

I'm having trouble installing Metasploit Framework on my MacBook, that's my configuration:
1) OS macOS Sierra 10.12.5
2) downloading the package metasploitframework-latest.pkg from http://osx.metasploit.com
3) installing the pkg file without any issue

When I try to launch the console app (msfconsole), I got this issue:

```
MacBook-di-Marzio:~ marzio$ **msfconsole** 
**Could not find nokogiri-1.7.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.**
```

I check in my system and the nonokiri packages is installed.
So I enter to this path of metasploit framework directory :
`/opt/metasploit-framework/embeded/framework`
and run the command:

```
bundle install
```

the bundle install every gem file needed without any problem but again no luck... it keeps giving me the error above:

```
MacBook-di-Marzio:~ marzio$ **msfconsole** 
Could not find nokogiri-1.7.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.**
```

my ruby framework as follow:

```
MacBook-di-Marzio:share marzio$ **ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]**
```

and...

```
MacBook-di-Marzio:share marzio$ **rbenv versions
  system
  * 2.4.1 (set by /Users/marzio/.rbenv/version)**
```

and..

```
  MacBook-di-Marzio:share marzio$ which ruby
  /Users/marzio/.rbenv/shims/ruby

  MacBook-di-Marzio:share marzio$ which gem
  /Users/marzio/.rbenv/shims/gem

  MacBook-di-Marzio:share marzio$ which bundle
 /Users/marzio/.rbenv/shims/bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command `bundle install` in the path `/opt/metasploit-framework/`.